# How to serialize output from custom method to JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialize output from specific method (The name of method doesn't start with `get` prefix).

```
class MyClass {
    // private fields with getters & setters

    public String customMethod() {
        return "some specific output";
    }
}
```

*Example of JSON*

```
{
    "fields-from-getter-methods": "values",
    "customMethod": "customMethod"
}
```

Output from `customMethod()` is not serialized to JSON field. How can I achieve serialization of the output from `customMethod()` **without adding of** `get` **prefix**?

Comment: add a dummy get custom method just for serialization? \

Comment: Please read the question carefully.

Comment: This should help. @JsonProperty("customeMethod")

Comment: Yes, it's the right annotation. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use JsonProperty annotation in your method.

With Jackson2:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MyClass {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("customMethod")
public String customMethod() {
    return "test";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    MyClass test = new MyClass();
    test.setName("myName");

    try {
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(test));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Output:

`{"name":"myName","customMethod":"test"}`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be a solution?

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class POJOWithFields {
  private int value;
}
```

source: [Changing property auto-detection](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#changing-property-auto-detection)

Answer (score 1):

This should help. @JsonProperty("customMethod")